# What is meant by $sup(A\cup B )$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I am given two subsets $A,B$ of $\mathbb{R}$ which are not empty and are bounded above.

Now according to a lemma, both of these sets have supremums. My issue is part of the question deals with sup$(A\cup B )$.  What exacty does that mean?

Comment: Are you asking what the symbol $\cup$ means? It is [set union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)).

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. It's obviously not the sum supA and supB. What exactly does the unity of two supremums mean beyond the literal meaning?

Comment: The most likely circumstance is that $A,B$ are subsets of a totally ordered set.  The word "group" often refers not to sets per se, but to a structure studied in abstract algebra, e.g. a "group" of permutations, etc.

Comment: Well, both $A$ and $B$ are sets, and $A\cup B$ is a set. So what is the supremum of $A\cup B$, i.e. $\sup (A\cup B)$?

Comment: Not the "unity(?) of two supremums" but the supremum of the union of two sets.  Parentheses make a difference.

Comment: Let's define $a\in A$ and $ b \in B$ such that  $\forall b,a$  $a\lt b$ Now would $supA\cup B$ just be supB since we're unifying the two sets?

Comment: You should really try to clarify the Question through editing.  What are $A,B$?  Are these sets of real numbers?

Comment: @hardmath I didn't want to lay out the entire question and have it solved, but I guess more context was needed in order to solve my question. A and B are two sets of real numbers that aren't empty and are upper bounded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, remind yourself of what sup($A$) means.  sup($A$) is the least upper bound of $A$.  That is, it's the number $s$ such that every element of $A$ is less than or equal to $s$.  In addition, $s$ is less than or equal to any other upper bound on $A$.

Your question has to do with taking the sup of a union.  It means exactly the same thing as it did before, only your input, your set, has changed.  Recall what $A\cup B$ means.  $A\cup B$ is the collection of all elements that are in either $A$ or $B$.  So, when looking for sup($A\cup B$), we seek the smallest upper bound for the set $A\cup B$.  Is it sup($A$)?  Is it sup($B$)?  Is it a linear combination of the two?  Is it, perhaps, some other function of sup($A$) and sup($B$)?  Perhaps you can do some investigating now.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for such a concise answer !

Comment: You are very welcome :)